# extract values from unique keys in R from a json file

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I am trying to convert a multiple JSON files in CSVs.

from translation_map, I need to get the nl value, nl audio and en value as columns in a dataframe.

So far I have this code written:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)


files <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".json", all.files=FALSE,
           full.names=FALSE)

data <- fromJSON(files[1])
```

I tried to use `fromJSON(files[1], flatten = TRUE)` but that didn't work.

The unique values for the keys throw me off here. Also I am not sure what to do about the

```
"str_empty": {
      "nl": {},
      "en": {}
```

part of the json file.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you supplied does not seem to be valid. I found two problems:

> "structure": [ a lot of things.
> ],

This throws an error, as the square brackets are problematic here. If you exchange these with quotation marks it is fine.

Also you seem to have one curly bracket `}` too much at the end. This might be the reason why you can't read the file and end up with an error message

The empty key-value pairs are in fact not a problem - they will be translated by `jsonlite` as empty named list.

You can then try indexing your resulting data.frame via

```
dat$translation_map[[1]]
```

OR

```
dat$translation_map[[2]][[1]]
```

and with a few loops you should be able to pull out the values that are of interest for you.

You could also try to flatten the resulting nested list into a named vector and use `grep` on its names to find desired values:

```
library(jsonlite)
dat<-fromJSON("your correct file.json")

dat2<-unlist(dat)
indices<-grep("nl.value",names(dat2))
dat2[indices]
```

(But maybe there is a more elegant way...)

Comment: using your second method I got really close. the only problem is that, nl.audio has only 12 observations while the rest have 37. I take the observations where there is an nl.audio available. 

does that make sense?

Comment: Hard for me to give you good feedback as I don't know your data as good as you do and don't know how you want to process it further. You are certainly right to have a very, very close look to see if the commands worked they way intended and if they caught really all the data you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

The elements in you JSON have different `length`: 1, 8 or 10.

```
test <- fromJSON("C:/GP/trash/test.json",flatten = T)
> summary(test)
                Length Class  Mode     
id               1     -none- character
class            1     -none- character
type             1     -none- character
content          8     -none- list     
structure        1     -none- character
translation_map 10     -none- list
```

You can convert the elements with the same length as a dataframe:

```
test[c('id', 'class', 'type', "structure")] %>% as.data.frame()
   id     class      type        structure
1 ob6 objective objective a lot of things.
```

But should decide what to do with the other ones.

Comment: I actually only need the translation_map and the nl value, nl audio and eb value from inside of that list

Comment: specifically where there is an "nl audio" that exists